Pandas: Querying for rows that share multiple values in a large dataset
Context: I am working with sports data specifically, and I have a dataset of over 700k rows. Each row corresponds to an athlete's performance in a season within a league in a particular year. I want to look for athletes who changed divisions (1) within a season, and (2) between one season and another season.
Consider the following example dataframe, in which the Id is equivalent to a unique identifier for a given athlete:
Id  Name       Division    Year
-------------------------------
01 Edgar      D2          2015
01 Edgar      D1          2016
01 Edgar      D1          2017
01 Edgar      D2          2018
02 Charlie    D2          2015
02 Charlie    D2          2016
02 Charlie    D1          2016
02 Charlie    D1          2017
02 Charlie    D1          2018
03 Will       D2          2015
03 Will       D1          2015
03 Will       D1          2016
03 Will       D1          2017
03 Will       D2          2018
04 Frank      D2          2015
04 Frank      D2          2016
04 Frank      D1          2016
04 Frank      D2          2017
04 Frank      D1          2017
04 Frank      D2          2018

The first expected output contains rows where an athlete appears in more than one division in one season:
Id  Name       Division    Year
-------------------------------
02 Charlie    D2          2016
02 Charlie    D1          2016
03 Will       D2          2015
03 Will       D1          2015
04 Frank      D2          2016
04 Frank      D1          2016
04 Frank      D2          2017
04 Frank      D1          2017

The second expected output would look for a player changing divisions year over year. Expected output:
Id  Name       Division    Year
-------------------------------
01 Edgar      D2          2015
01 Edgar      D1          2016
01 Edgar      D1          2017
01 Edgar      D2          2018
02 Charlie    D2          2015
02 Charlie    D2          2016
02 Charlie    D1          2016
02 Charlie    D1          2017
03 Will       D2          2015
03 Will       D1          2015
03 Will       D1          2016
03 Will       D1          2017
03 Will       D2          2018
04 Frank      D2          2015
04 Frank      D2          2016
04 Frank      D1          2016
04 Frank      D2          2017
04 Frank      D1          2017
04 Frank      D2          2018


IIUC, check the following approaches. I'm assuming your second expected dataframe isn't what you want, as it's the same as the original and doesn't correspond to the description of desired output.

rows where an athlete appears in more than one division in one season

changed_within_season = df[df.duplicated(["Id", "Year"], keep=False)]

    Id     Name Division  Year
5   02  Charlie       D2  2016
6   02  Charlie       D1  2016
9   03     Will       D2  2015
10  03     Will       D1  2015
15  04    Frank       D2  2016
16  04    Frank       D1  2016
17  04    Frank       D2  2017
18  04    Frank       D1  2017


look for a player changing divisions year over year [and] the query needs to look for a mismatch between any rows corresponding to a previous year

filter_df = (
    df.groupby(["Id", "Year"], as_index=False)["Division"]
    .agg(",".join)
    .assign(
        PreviousDivision=lambda x: x["Division"]
        .shift()
        .where(x["Id"] == x["Id"].shift())
    )
)

id_mask = filter_df["Id"] != filter_df["Id"].shift(-1)
division_mask = (filter_df["Division"] != filter_df["PreviousDivision"]) & (
    filter_df["Division"] != filter_df["PreviousDivision"].shift(-1)
)

filter_df.loc[id_mask] = filter_df[division_mask]
filter_df["Division"] = filter_df["Division"].str.split(",")

changed_between_seasons = df.merge(
    filter_df.drop(columns="PreviousDivision").explode("Division"), how="inner"
)

    Id     Name Division  Year
0   01    Edgar       D2  2015
1   01    Edgar       D1  2016
2   01    Edgar       D1  2017
3   01    Edgar       D2  2018
4   02  Charlie       D2  2015
5   02  Charlie       D2  2016
6   02  Charlie       D1  2016
7   02  Charlie       D1  2017
8   03     Will       D2  2015
9   03     Will       D1  2015
10  03     Will       D1  2016
11  03     Will       D1  2017
12  03     Will       D2  2018
13  04    Frank       D2  2015
14  04    Frank       D2  2016
15  04    Frank       D1  2016
16  04    Frank       D2  2017
17  04    Frank       D1  2017
18  04    Frank       D2  2018


The first solution is perfect. Thank you. The second suffers maybe from me being inexact in the wording or example, because an athlete can play in more than one division in a year, so the query needs to look for a mismatch between any rows corresponding to a previous year. In my example, it does end up returning most of the rows.

@d-fws Ok, I see it now. Check my updated answer.
